# CSS height not responding when skrollr is turned off

Tags: javascript, html, css, skrollr

I am using Skrollr for my ipad and desktop sizes, but because I made the site responsive I turned Skrollr off so that my content would stack. One thing that I seem to be having trouble with is getting my content containers (sections tags) to resize to the height of the window. They default back to the hight of whatever content is inside those tags, even thought the css is giving a min-height and a height of 100%. I"m getting this to work by forcing the height in javaScript, but I would think I shouldn't have to do this?

HTML

```
<section id='sectionOne' data-0="transform:translate(0%,0%);" data-100p="transform:translate(0%,-50%);"> <h1>SECTION 1</h1> </section>

<section id='sectionTwo' data-0="transform:translate(0%,100%);" data-200p="transform:translate(0%,0%);" data-300p="transform:translate(0%,-50%);"> <h1>SECTION 2</h1> </section>
```

CSS

```
html{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

}

```
body{
background-color: black;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

}

```
section{
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
border-top: black 1px solid;
```

}

```
#sectionOne{
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color:#00ff00;
```

}

```
#sectionOne{
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color:#ffb227;
```

}

javascript:

```
var s;

// set breakpoitns
$(window).setBreakpoints({
    // use only largest available vs use all available
    distinct: true, 
    // array of widths in pixels where breakpoints
    breakpoints: [
        320,
        480,
        768  
    ] 
}); 

$(window).bind('enterBreakpoint320',function() {
    console.log("this is now 320");

    if(s != undefined)
    {
        console.log('destroy');
        s = skrollr.init().destroy();
    }
    console.log(s);
});

$(window).bind('enterBreakpoint480',function() {
    console.log("this is now 480");

    if(s != undefined)
    {
        console.log('destroy');
        s = skrollr.init().destroy();
    }
    // force the sections to be the hight of the view port
    $('#sectionOne').height($(window).height());
    $('#sectionTwo').height($(window).height());
    console.log(s);
});

$(window).bind('enterBreakpoint768',function() {
    console.log("this is now 768");
    s = skrollr.init({
            forceHeight: true
        });
    console.log(s);

});
```